# How to make object transparent

Tags: light

[image]
I have a added a cube and delete the top and bottom faces. And given plastic material. I have added a ico-sphere inside that cube and given emission light to it. I want the light should come out from the cube. I want to get the lantern effect. Image of lantern is attached. i want to achieve that effect. I have attach my blender file [image]  to know what material i have use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a translucent shader and mix it with your current shader.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Final]

The best looking result you can achieve by using ***Subsurface Scattering*** shader.

[image: Nodes]

The other options could be also:

1. Mix *Diffuse* shader with *Transparent* shader - this will give you visible emission material trough it.
2. *Translucent* shader - the inside of the lantern will not be affected by light.
3. *Diffuse* mixed with *Translucent* - will be very close to *Subsurface Scattering*. You will want to mix it with Transparent shader.

*Note that I've bumped Emission material to 20.*