# How to make such a material (Frosted glass)

Tags: materials

Tell me how to make the material as in the blue circle in the photo and glass in front. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! Although this is certainly an interesting question, the bare minimum here is to show some effort towards your goal, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Please edit your question and add what you've tried so far *or* eg. some geometry at least to get the ball rolling. Also I commend take the tour to learn about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, Thanks.

Comment: Previous posts: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32026/31447, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87369/31447 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87635/31447

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try with Eevee, basically it's a *Principled BSDF* with *Roughness* at 0.6, *Transmission* at 0.97 and *IOR* at 1.23 (nothing very scientific here, probably needs to be tweaked), I've mixed it with a *Glossy BSDF* with a *Layer Weight* as factor in order to have more reflections on its periphery, and give it a *Bump* with a thin noise:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. But can you tell me how you made the lighting

Comment: it's just 2 suns and 2 areas, nothing very complicated