# How do I make a rough plastic surface?

Tags: texturing, materials, topology

How do I make a rough plastic surface?

I created a bottle and need to make this bottle like in the picture.
How to make these rhombuses like in the picture?

[image]

Comment: maybe check my answer here, it's pretty close, except a bit less transparent: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205992/how-to-make-such-a-material-frosted-glass/205999#205999

Comment: Thank you . But how i can draw this shapes ?

Comment: do it procedurally with a Noise Texture, the one you can see on my screenshot, that is plugged into a Bump node

Comment: Can you please show an example how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? You just need to copy the exact same setup as the one I've linked, then select the faces of your object that are supposed to have this material (you need to have the correct topology of course) and click on Assign, it should work fine, you'll just need to tweak some values like Transmission

Comment: I mean, how do you do the right topology for this?

Comment: if your question is about topology you should edit it, maybe add pictures if you have other views of the same object?

Comment: I added another picture. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This has to do with normals. In Blender Internal it was as easy as Geometry>Influence>Normals and you only needed to adjust the value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to illustrate moonboots's comment.

1. Use Noise texture with a Bump node.
2. Set Bump node *Distance* to around 0,001 or less (1 milimeter)
3. Done.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How to make these rhombuses like in the picture?

Comment: Hello :). We're trying to keep it one question per post on this site. If you have another question, feel free to ask it as a new post - you can link this one to provide context.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the "smooth" areas with a pattern like in the image, you can mask some parts of your Bump Map by multiplying it with a (rotated) checker texture. You will probably have to make a lot of transformation adjustments (size, rotation, location, etc..) before it fits your project perfectly, though:

[image: Bottle]