# Realistic Car back lights [Cycles]

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

So I was working on a night scene with a model of a mustang. My scene looks similar to this:
[image: Car lights]

I was wondering if anyone knew how to produce the glow of the rear lights; how they start orange, but are red around the edges.

This is what I have tried so far:
[image: First Try]
The light source is a point lamp behind the glass.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here is the lights isolated from the rest of the car:
[image]

Here is the wireframe:
[image]
*the four dark circles are the front lights*

there is a point lamp behind them and the back grey part is glossy with 0.2 roughness

**Edit 2:**
Changed to Filmic colorspace:
[image]

**Edit 3:**
Final Render using Luke D's suggestion:
[image]

**Edit4:**

Here's the blend file of the rear lights:
 [image]

**Edit5:**

Second Render after Luke D's suggestion:
[image]
I think it came out rather nice.

Comment: Could you please provide more screenshots of this model back lights? Or just the name of the model itself. It looks to me like the inside of this light is colored.

Comment: Make sure to use "Filmic" Colorspace, your intensity of the lights is not quite high enough. Also show use the wireframe of the glas or upload a model.

Comment: I just added the wireframe and isolated image of the rear lights. I also changed to filmic color space

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66047/how-to-make-object-transparent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Final image with Compositing:

[image: final]

Different **Color Ramp** and **Mapping** node setups.

[image: variations]

### Scene overview:

Scene has three elements Emission source, Glass mesh and mesh to enclosed both of them. Also HDRI lightning.

[image: scene]

### Emission source:

Three **Spheres** with **Emission** shader mixed with **Transparent** (pure white, #FFF) by **Light Path** > **is Camera Ray**. We don't want to see'em.

[image: emission]

### Glass mesh and material:

**Material:**

Most important thing here. It's colored **Transparent Shader** mixed with **Glossy** by **Layer Weight** to have glass like reflection and to let light go trough. Don't forget to set **Mapping** node accordingly to your mesh.

You can control how much white, orange and red color you want.

[image: glass]

**Mesh:**

This is just quick mesh created with **Poke Face**.

[image: mesh]

### Final thoughts:

I've used also **Glare** node in **Compositing** to have nicer overall look.

[image: compositing]

### Blend file:

Without HDRI lightning.

[image]

Comment: Roight. Will try this and get back to you

Comment: right so this kind just doesn't work with the scene I have put up an image of the final render using this method

Comment: @Grimlock  
Strip only light part from the blend file and upload it to: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com It's hard to tell just from the screenshot. Maybe it's because of the mesh behind the light. If it's not white diffuse it could lead to such result. Did you check my blend file? Is there everything ok?

Comment: I just uploaded the model of the rear lights

Comment: @Grimlock It's because you have set Clamp Direct (4) and Indirect (1). Setting it back to 0, 0 bring light strength to normal.

Comment: I'll look into it amd get back to you

Comment: I just rendered out an image with those settings and it worked; I've put up a rendered image. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The white in the shot isn't from the colour of the bulb; it is from the colour blowing out on the image capture device. Hence adding white to a colour ramp, like lightsabers and fire, might not quite be the desired effect in more contexts. Lean on the synthetic imaging transform and increase the emission.

Comment: @troy_s white in Color Ramp is for full transparency: https://imgur.com/nHHHJwN